# how to send image file on php server using http post method in android application

Tags: android

i want to send image file on my php server not upload on php server....i want to only send to php server by using post method...so pls tell me about dat..and help me..

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to upload image in php server using android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140878/how-to-upload-image-in-php-server-using-android-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
try {
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```